# Create link from GET parameter

Tags: php

Im trying to create some links depending on the GET parametre currently set.

My URL looks like this:

```
http://mysite.com/index.php?bar=test&page=page
```

In my code I do the following:

```
$bar = $_REQUEST['bar'];
<a href="index.php?bar=<?php echo $bar?>&page=anotherpage"
```

But every time I click the link, it adds the whole string to the URL again.

Like first click would give me this URL:

```
http://mysite.com/index.php?bar=test&page=anotherpagepage=anotherpage
```

And next click creates:

```
http://mysite.com/index.php?bar=test&page=anotherpagepage=anotherpagepage=anotherpage
```

And so on.

Is there any way to only get the request once so that the URL always looks like this:

```
http://mysite.com/index.php?bar=test&page=anotherpage
```

No matter how many times I click the link?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: the issue is with your paths, try this with absolute paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed an ampersand in your first example. (&amp;). Give this a try:

```
$bar = $_REQUEST['bar'];
<a href="index.php?bar=<?php echo $bar?>&amp;page=anotherpage"
```

Or even better, escape your variables before use to prevent XSS, Cross Site Scripting security vulnerability. Use `urlencode()` for URLs. 
http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php:

```
$bar = $_REQUEST['bar'];
<a href="index.php?bar=<?=urlencode($bar)?>&amp;page=anotherpage"
```

Comment: Are there any browsers where using the ampresand sign (&) and not the entity (&amp;) would give you any trouble? In my experience, browsers url-encodes it like this anyways.

Comment: @EsbenTind Probably not, but the encoding of & as &amp; is required in HTML. & does not validate in HTML documents.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look on the php function [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

That enables you to construct your array first, like this:

```
$query = array("bar"=>$_REQUEST['bar'], "page"=>"anotherpage")
echo '<a href="/index.php?'.http_build_query($query).'">Link</a>';
```